# debug python code running in docker container from host using vscode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a container running on my host with a python process and I have the vs code installed on the host. Is it possible to debug the python process from the host installed vscode ? If yes, how can this be achieved ?

Comment: Did you try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python?

Comment: I have a python process which is already running. Looks like the above link starts the process

Comment: @user2599052 -Could you describe your needs in detail for us? Please try to refer to the content of the python file in the debugging container in this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python#_build-run-and-debug-the-container).

Comment: @JillCheng. Say I have a container where a python process for example flask is already running. Now when I connect to a running container from within vscode, I would like to debug that python process. How to achieve this. I see an option of connecting to a local python process for debugging but I don't see any python process getting listed by vscode. I can start  a process from within vscode and debug it though.

Comment: @user2599052 -After you connect to the container, a new VSCode interface will be opened, and you could add a working folder to it and operate, such as putting the project directory in the container into it for debugging.

Comment: @JillCheng yes I am already doing it.  The question is that since the context of vscode has changed after connecting to container, it should be able to detect the running python processes inside the container and allow me to debug that process.

Comment: @user2599052 -This is the process of using VSCode to simulate the environment in the docker container. Have you tried manually entering the file path in the container?

Comment: @JillCheng which file path are you referring to ? If you are talking about python file, then yes I am able to debug that way, but I would be interested to know abt connecting to already running process

Comment: How to understand "connecting to already running process"? Do you want VSCode to automatically detect the running process in the container after connecting to the container?

Comment: Actually I think I got it. though I need to give it a try. I am talking about the debug configuration which allows us to attach using process id..

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not know what python process you have running, I'll use FastAPI as an example.

1. First, you need to define a new configuration in the file `<project_root>/.vscode/launch.json`. To access this file, you can go to the **Run & Debug** section on the activity bar, and press the cog/wheel at the top.

Add a new item in the **configurations** like shown below.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "connect": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 5678
        },
        "pathMappings": [
            {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "."
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Now you need to include **debugpy**. If you are using a requirements file, you can just add it there. If you use **Poetry**, you can run `poetry add debugpy` in your terminal (the Dockerfile example shows how you can use Poetry in a docker image).
3. *First option* - In your **Dockerfile** you need to run **debugpy** and make it listen for port **5678**.
   Now the debugger will start every time you run the container and await attachment.

```
FROM python:3.10.0

# Set the working directory:
WORKDIR /usr/src

# Copy the pyproject.toml file (or requirements.txt) to cache them in the docker layer:
COPY [ "./src/pyproject.toml", "./"]

# Set the python path if needed.
# For example, if main.py is not located in the project root:
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:${PWD}"

# Upgrade pip and install Poetry:
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install poetry==1.1.12

# Project initialization using Poetry:
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Run the application:
CMD ["python", "-m", "debugpy", "--wait-for-client", "--listen", "0.0.0.0:5678", "-m", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload", "--reload-exclude", "tests"]

EXPOSE 8000 5678
```

4. *Second option* - Set up the debugger in the main.py file by adding the lines below. This means that the debugger will be attached to the container when it starts; if the debugger variable is set to True.

```py
debugger = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if debugger:
        import debugpy
        debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
        debugpy.wait_for_client()

    uvicorn.run(
        "main:app",
        host="localhost",
        port=8000,
        log_level="info",
        reload=True,
    )
```

5. Both examples need the **Dockerfile** to expose the port **5678**.
   Now, after running the container, the debugger will "pause" and await attachment. To attach the debugger, go back to **Run & Debug** section on the activity bar in VSCode and select `Python: Remote Attach` from the dropdown menu and press play.

Now you should be able to use the debugger inside the docker container.